# How does Mocha know that done was specified?

Tags: node.js, tdd, mocha.js

If I write an asynchronous test using Mocha, all I need to do is to specify the done parameter on the test function:

```
test('foo', function (done) {...});
```

My question is: How does Mocha know whether done was given?

The definition of the test function should be something such as

```
function test(title, fn) {...};
```

How does Mocha check fn?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It uses the `.length` property on the test function.

To illustrate, try this in the Node REPL:

```
> (function() {}).length
0
> (function(done) {}).length
1
```

Here's the actual [line in the source](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/4b05a59ed249095496a29930c975dfccd056e64e/lib/runnable.js#L43) where this check happens:

```
this.async = fn && fn.length;
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't know that such a property exists on functions :-)

Comment: No problem.  That check happens on the `fn` reference.